# .NET 2.0 webservice not returning DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, mono, datatable

I have a webservice method defined as so:

```
[WebMethod]
public DataTable GetResponseCodeTypes()
{
  // connect to database and retrieve results,
  // then populate and return a DataTable
}
```

The method has been verified via the webservice test form and returns a `DataTable` as expected:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DataTable xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
  <DocumentElement xmlns="">
    <ResponseCodeTypes>
      <CodeTypeId>1</CodeTypeId>
      <Descrip>RPC</Descrip>
    </ResponseCodeTypes>
    <ResponseCodeTypes>
      <CodeTypeId>2</CodeTypeId>
      <Descrip>Non-RPC</Descrip>
    </ResponseCodeTypes>
    <ResponseCodeTypes>
      <CodeTypeId>3</CodeTypeId>
      <Descrip>No connect</Descrip>
    </ResponseCodeTypes>
  </DocumentElement>
</DataTable>
```

However, when I call the `GetResponseCodeTypes` method from my C# frontend code, not only does it return a `DataSet` instead of a `DataTable`, but the returned `DataSet` contains zero tables.

I then went and modified the stub class (generated by Visual Studio when a web reference is added) to return a `DataTable` instead. This works, inasmuch as I do get a `DataTable` back - but said `DataTable` has no columns or rows defined.

I know in .NET 1.x it was not possible to return a `DataTable` from a webservice method (you had to wrap it in a `DataSet`) but I was under the impression that this was fixed in .NET 2.x...

What is the issue here?

**EDIT:**

The webservice is .NET 2.0, running on a Linux box under Mono 2.4.2.3; while the frontend code is being developed in .NET 2.0 on a Windows XP machine running VS2008 with SP1.

Answer (score 0):

As per this link [DataTable and Webservice in ADO.NET 2.0](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=108282)

> Please note that DataTable itself
>   supports Web-Services, the only thing
>   that's broken is the proxy-generation,
>   once the proxy is created, at runtime,
>   a DataTable instance can be passed
>   around using WebServices.
>
> For the interim period, you may choose
>   any of the following workarounds:
>
> A) Manually create the client side
>   proxy class for each WebService that
>   uses DataTable
>
> B)
>
> 1. compile and GAC the attached SchemaImporterExtension file.
> 2. add it to the existent extensions in machine.config, using
>      fully-qualified assembly name
> 3. Use the standard mechanisms (like xsd.exe or Visual Studio) to generate
>      the client-side proxy class

Comment: Thanks Ramesh - I tried that but it didn't make any difference to the proxy class generated by VS/wsdl.exe. I edited my original post with some more information, could it be Mono causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should not return `DataTable`, `DataSet`, or any other type that is specific to .NET. Naturally, they will only work with .NET clients.

Comment: That's not a problem because I know for a fact that the webservice will never be consumed by anything other than .NET.